# Case expressions may only be nested to level 10 error in SQL query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, view, nested, case

I have original query on server1 and need to create it on server 2. I am able to create the View but while executing it I am getting error at CASE statement as below:

```
Error:

    Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    Statement(s) could not be prepared.
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near 'Qry1097'.
    Msg 125, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
    Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.
```

Query:
    SELECT

```
ID, Forename, Surname, 

Code, Description, 

Grade, Dept,

Course, Title, 

CASE WHEN Code IN ('VJ028') THEN 'FUNCTIONAL SKILLS - LEVEL 1 & LEVEL 2' 

WHEN Code IN ('VE203', '22877C')  THEN 'WRITING - LEVEL 2' 

WHEN Code IN ('VE202', 'VE201')  THEN 'READING - LEVEL 2' 

WHEN Code = 'VE201'  THEN 'SPEAKING & LISTENING' 

WHEN Code = 'RU243'  THEN 'ENTRY LEVEL' 

WHEN Code IN ('22875C') THEN 'E2 FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING & LISTENING' 

WHEN Code IN ('22876C', '22879C')  THEN 'E2 FUNCTIONAL SKILLS READING'  

WHEN Code = '22877C'  THEN 'E2 FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING'  

WHEN Code = '22878C'  THEN 'E3 FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING & LISTENING' 

WHEN Code = '22880C'  THEN 'E3 FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING'  

WHEN Code= '22879C' THEN  'E3 FUNCTIONAL SKILLS READING' 

WHEN Code = 'VE102'  THEN 'READING-LEVEL 1' 

WHEN Code = 'VE103'  THEN 'WRITING-LEVEL 1' 

WHEN Code = '3748-01'  THEN 'FUNCTIONAL SKILLS ENGLISH' 

WHEN Code = 'VE101'  THEN 'SPEAKING & LISTENING-LEVEL 1'

END AS SubjectCode,

CASE 

WHEN Description = 'FUNCTIONAL SKILLS - ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 & LEVEL  2)' THEN 'Overall'

WHEN Description = 'ENGLISH (ENTRY LEVEL)' THEN 'Overall'

WHEN Description = 'FUNCTIONAL SKILLS ENGLISH' THEN 'Overall'

WHEN Description = 'READING -ENGLISH LEVEL 2' THEN 'Reading'

WHEN Description = 'READING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 )' THEN 'Reading'

WHEN Description = 'E2 ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING' THEN 'Reading'

WHEN Description = 'E3 ENGLISH FUNTIONAL SKILLS READING' THEN 'Reading'

WHEN Description = 'WRITING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1 )' THEN 'Writing'

WHEN Description = 'WRITING- ENGLISH LEVEL  2' THEN 'Writing'

WHEN Description = 'E2 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING' THEN 'Writing'

WHEN Description = 'E3 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS WRITING' THEN 'Writing'

WHEN Description = 'SPEAKING & LISTENING- ENGLISH LEVEL 2' THEN 'Speaking & Listening'

WHEN Description = 'SPEAKING & LISTENING- ENGLISH (LEVEL 1)' THEN 'Speaking & Listening'

WHEN Description = 'E3 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING AND LISTENING' THEN 'Speaking & Listening'

WHEN Description = 'E2 ENGLISH FUNCTIONAL SKILLS SPEAKING AND LISTENING' THEN 'Speaking & Listening'

END AS CourseType,


CASE WHEN Act_Grade  = 'PA' THEN 'Pass'

WHEN e.EXSS_Act_Grade = 'FL'  THEN 'Fail'

WHEN e.EXSS_Act_Grade = 'XA'  THEN 'Not Attended'

END AS Grade

FROM Table
```

Error:

Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.

How can I correct this?

Comment: It would be better to have a table with the descriptions you want and then join them

Comment: If you're not able to create a table to hold these descriptions (which is the best option), you could possibly handle the aliasing in the report.

Comment: There is an excellent explanation of the issue here (including a potential solution): http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/why-do-linked-servers-have-a-limitation-of-10-branches-in-a-case-expression.
If the solution in the accepted answer works for you, please not it here so that this question can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parser does not see a nested CASE statement over 10 levels deep (though it does pass one on to the later stages of local query compilation).

Although a possible work around may be something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
CASE SUBSTRING(p.Name, 1, 1)
    WHEN 'a' THEN '1' 
    WHEN 'b' THEN '2' 
    WHEN 'c' THEN '3' 
    WHEN 'd' THEN '4' 
    WHEN 'e' THEN '5' 
    WHEN 'f' THEN '6' 
    WHEN 'g' THEN '7' 
    WHEN 'h' THEN '8' 
    WHEN 'i' THEN '9' 
    ELSE NULL
END,
CASE SUBSTRING(p.Name, 1, 1)
    WHEN 'j' THEN '10' 
    WHEN 'k' THEN '11'  
END)
FROM dbo.AdventureWorks.Sample AS p
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42837/why-do-linked-servers-have-a-limitation-of-10-branches-in-a-case-expression

Answer (score 0):

If the values are numeric another work around would be to simply add multiple case statements together. See below example.

```
select 
case when @Period=1 then Bal01 else 0 end +
case when @Period=2 then Bal02 else 0 end +
case when @Period=3 then Bal03 else 0 end +
case when @Period=4 then Bal04 else 0 end +
case when @Period=5 then Bal05 else 0 end +
case when @Period=6 then Bal06 else 0 end +
case when @Period=7 then Bal07 else 0 end +
case when @Period=8 then Bal08 else 0 end +
case when @Period=9 then Bal09 else 0 end +
case when @Period=10 then Bal10 else 0 end +
case when @Period=11 then Bal11 else  0 end +
case when @Period=12 then Bal12 else  0 end 

from VendorHistory
where Vendor = 'Staples'
```